# MVC; How to render the correct active tab after a postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view where I am using tabs. For each tab I have a partial view.
Where I select a tab and post the changes, and return the Partial View, the Partial View is the only thing that gets rendered, not the whole View.
I suspect I need to hijack the form in order to get round this. I am wondering how to do this.

My View;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Employee.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SHP.WebUI.Models.HolidayRequestViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    HolidayRequest
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="EmployeeContent" runat="server">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
    <h2>Holiday Request</h2>
    <p>You have <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DaysAvailableThisYear) %> days left annual leave for this year 
    and <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DaysAvailableNextYear) %> days left for next year.</p>
    <p>If your request is approved and exceeds the number of days left, then those extra days will not be paid.</p>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EmployeeId) %><%: Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ApproverId) %>
            <% } %>    
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Approver</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Single Date</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Date Range</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div id="tabs-1">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("GetApproverTab", Model); %>
         </div>
         <div id="tabs-2">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("GetSingleDateTab", Model); %>
         </div>
         <div id="tabs-3">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("GetDateRangeTab", Model); %>
         </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

My Partial View;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.WebUI.Models.HolidayRequestViewModel>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("GetSingleDateTab", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmSingleDate" }))
       { %>
<p>Enter your day or part day of Annual Leave here.</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Date:</td>
        <td><%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.SingleDate) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Morning Only:</td>
        <td><%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.MorningOnlyFlag) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Afternoon Only:</td>
        <td><%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.MorningOnlyFlag) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%: Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EmployeeId) %><%: Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ApproverId) %>
    <% } %>
```

My Controller;

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HolidayRequest(HolidayRequestViewModel hrvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            hrvm.Update();
            return View(new HolidayRequestViewModel(hrvm.EmployeeId));
        }
        return View(hrvm);
    }

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSingleDateTab(HolidayRequestViewModel hrvm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        hrvm.Update();
        return PartialView(new HolidayRequestViewModel(hrvm.EmployeeId));
    }
    return PartialView(hrvm);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you'll need to check the requested/ posted URL to check for the #name on the end, and then redirect to that URL.

You could do the same with Javascript and a hidden field, updating it on tab click and checking on the server.

Additionally, you could change the output on the view to set the selected one based on the URL/ posted hidden field, if you want to keep your URLs cleaner and code simpler.

Comment: +1 for hidden field. I don't think #name is valid for all browsers across all platforms.

Comment: You can check the requested URL to see if it ends with #<SOMENAME>, if it does, it will means that the user has gone to a bookmark - hopefully one of your tabs. If they had, you can modify the output of the view to account for the tab being selected...maybe by adding an additional class to the anchor. Your javascript can then check for it and select the appropriate tab. Same trick with the hidden field, only you'll check the value of that, rather than muck about with the URL.

Comment: I am also learning Javascript. I am imagining from your answer that I Have a form.load() event, and then I pick up an object from which I can check for a hidden field and from that I can make the correct tab active. I do not know how to do this.

Comment: That's exactly right, these are different questions though, so it may be worth asking them as separate ones. Also, you may want to look into the use of jQuery instead of using plain javascript.